# why cmd can not run "python a.py",but "python E:\python\python2.79\a.py"is ok..."python a.py"is taught by a python book

Tags: python

Just like I ask in the title
I try to run "python a.py" in cmd but it says no such file or directory
"python E:\python\python2.79\a.py" can run..
..I am a newbie in python...I will appeciate for your answers

Comment: What directory are you in when you type `python a.py`?

Comment: C:\users\Administrator>

Comment: thank you!! I konw where I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are not in the same directory as `a.py`. If so, you will need the absolute path rather than the relative path. That is probably why `python (location of a.py)` runs but `python a.py` will not. Make sure that you are running a.py from the same directory as you saved it in.

Comment: Took me a little while to learn the same thing. Continue working. Python is a fun language

Comment: yeah..I am a student majoy in civil engineering ..but I think IT will be more instersting..so I learn python first

Comment: It was the first language I really learned too. I have been able to use python and my Engineering major to land amazing internship opportunities building wearable electronics.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you're using a shell, you're positioned in a directory in the filesystem. The first example, `python a.py` uses a relative path; it says "the file I want to run is `a.py` in the very same directory I'm currently in". The second example, `python E:\python\python2.79\a.py` uses an absolute path; it says "no matter where I'm in the filesystem, the complete path to the file I want to run is this one". Then, simply, if you're not in the directory where `a.py` is, and you run `python a.py`, `python` will say it couldn't find that file.